# How to convert column values into rows PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, unpivot

**This is my query:**

```
SELECT * FROM profile_change_set where id = '1558079b-d954-4a0d-b241-b39fe8f3498c';
```

| id | table_name | column_key | column_value | operation_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1558079b-d954-4a0d-b241-b39fe8f3498c | farmers | smsEnabled | somvalue | update |

**What is want is to convert all values into rows.**

| column_key | column_value |
| --- | --- |
| id | 1558079b-d954-4a0d-b241-b39fe8f3498c |
| table_name | farmers |
| column_key | smsEnabled |
| column_value | somvalue |
| operation_type | update |

**Any help, thank you in advance.**

Comment: If you are using `psql`, you can turn that output on using the `\x` [meta command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS)

Comment: I'm running this query on Navicat IDE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JSON features to turn columns into rows:

```
select cols.*
from profile_change_set pcs
  cross join jsonb_each_text(to_jsonb(pcs)) as cols(column_key, column_value)
where pcs.id = ...;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try use table function [CROSSTAB](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tablefunc.html) (analogue PIVOT function in SQL Server)

And take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query), in that answer, an intermediate table is used as a variable, and after that on this variable use CROSSTAB. Take a look at this way